# pass property from one viewmodel to another viewmodel in mvvm wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

trying to pass a selected row in wpf datagrid in one viewmodel to another viewmodel for editing. I can select the row and have it in a property. but can't pass it to another property in a different viewmodel.

this is the code from the viewmodel where the row is selected:

```
using Checkbook8.Data;

using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace Checkbook8.Views
{
    internal class ChkbkTransactionListViewModel : BindableBase
    {
        private ObservableCollection<ChkbkTransaction>? _ChkbkRecordCol;

        public ChkbkTransactionListViewModel()
        {
            GetData();
        }

        private void GetData()
        {
            using (var context = new ChkbkTransactionDbContext())
            {
                _ChkbkRecordCol = new ObservableCollection<ChkbkTransaction>   (context.ChkbkTransactions.ToList());
            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<ChkbkTransaction>? ChkbkRecordCol
        {
            get => _ChkbkRecordCol;
            set => SetProperty(ref _ChkbkRecordCol, value);
        }

        private static ChkbkTransaction? _SelectedTransaction;
        public ChkbkTransaction? SelectedTransaction
        {
            get => _SelectedTransaction;
            set => SetProperty(ref _SelectedTransaction, value);
        }

        private static ChkbkTransactionListViewModel _Instance = new();
        public static ChkbkTransactionListViewModel Instance { get {  return _Instance; } }

    }
}
```

and this is the code on where I am trying to pass SelectedTransaction property to:

```
using Checkbook8.Data;

namespace Checkbook8.Views
{
    internal class EditTransactionViewModel : BindableBase
    {
        private ChkbkTransaction _TransactionSelected;
        public ChkbkTransaction TransactionSelected
        {
            get => _TransactionSelected;
            set
            {
                value = ChkbkTransactionListViewModel.Instance.SelectedTransaction;
                SetProperty(ref _TransactionSelected, value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have challenge in decoupling code and passing data between two ViewModels, consider using an `EventAggregator` pattern. This can help achieve loose coupling and enhance the maintainability of your code.

First, create an `EventAggregator` class:

```cs
public static class EventAggregator
{
    public static event EventHandler<DataEventArgs>? DataPassed;

    public static void PublishData(object data)
    {
        DataPassed?.Invoke(null, new DataEventArgs(data));
    }
}

public class DataEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public object Data { get; }

    public DataEventArgs(object data)
    {
        Data = data;
    }
}
```

Next, in the source ViewModel where you want to send the data:

```cs
using Checkbook8.Data;

namespace Checkbook8.Views
{
    internal class ChkbkTransactionListViewModel : BindableBase
    {
        // Other codes ...

        private static ChkbkTransaction? _SelectedTransaction;
        public ChkbkTransaction? SelectedTransaction
        {
            get => _SelectedTransaction;
            set {
                SetProperty(ref _SelectedTransaction, value);
                EventAggregator.PublishData(value); // Publish the message
            }
        }

        // Other codes ...

    }
}
```

And in the receiving ViewModel:

```cs
using Checkbook8.Data;

namespace Checkbook8.Views
{
    internal class EditTransactionViewModel : BindableBase
    {
        public EditTransactionViewModel()
        {
            EventAggregator.DataPassed += EventAggregator_DataPassed;
        }

        private void EventAggregator_DataPassed(object? sender, DataEventArgs e)
        {
            TransactionSelected = e.Data;
        }

        private ChkbkTransaction _TransactionSelected;
        public ChkbkTransaction TransactionSelected
        {
            get => _TransactionSelected;
            set => SetProperty(ref _TransactionSelected, value);
        }
    }
}
```

This way, you can efficiently pass data between ViewModels without direct dependencies, promoting a more modular and maintainable codebase.

Comment: This worked very well. Will remember this for future projects. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The setter of `EditTransactionViewModel.TransactionSelected` is a little unusual. It seems never invoked, and it ignores the value passed in, which is really odd. So you might just remove the setter and rather keep the editable `TransactionSelected` property
in sync with the one in `ChkbkTransactionListViewModel`.
This is one way to do it:

```
internal class EditTransactionViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public EditTransactionViewModel()
    {
        ChkbkTransactionListViewModel.Instance.PropertyChanged += (o, e) => 
        {
            if (e.PropertyName == nameof(ChkbkTransactionListViewModel.TransactionSelected)
            {
                SetProperty(ref _TransactionSelected,
                    ChkbkTransactionListViewModel.Instance.TransactionSelected);
            }
        };
    }

    private ChkbkTransaction _TransactionSelected;
    public ChkbkTransaction TransactionSelected => _TransactionSelected;
}
```

Also in ChkbkTransaction : don't declare `_SelectedTransaction` as `static` when the property is an instance property (even if it is a singleton).

Comment: this doesn't work either, but i thank you for the suggestion. i think that i may have to redesign the whole application .